# How to show a layout when pull down android

Tags: android, android-layout, pull-to-refresh

I am making an android app. In which I have a scenario. First watch screenshot below so anyone come here to answer has some clear picture that what I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqCri.png

**What I want:** grey submenu is hidden by default but appears from down when user pulls down. And slowly hide up, when the user pulls up at the same time when the grey menu is slowly appearing down, also the top 4 icons will go slowly down and grow at the same time.

Comment: Try using a BottomSheetDialog